# Blocked my country for .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, magento, ip

I have generated blocked some country list on ip2location for .htaccess file.Everything it's ok but if I blocked my country ,how can I access on my computer in my country? Do you have any idea for .htaccess settings?

```html
<Limit GET HEAD POST>
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from 1.0.1.0/24
deny from 1.0.2.0/23
deny from 1.0.8.0/21
</Limit>
```

Comment: You have no code posted so how can anyone suggest? Try just allowing your IP and block the rest.

Comment: add code to your question.

Comment: Updated code for question